# How to link code that is compatible with other version of java

Tags: java, jvm

My existing server is running on Java 1.6 and I cant upgrade it.

I need to use some third party jar/api that is compatible with `Java 1.8`, when I write some code to access its API, eclipse throws

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version`

How I can proceed now? Not sure if this is duplicate question, if yes please provide some link on this.

Comment: You can't. Only one ``JDK`` per project can be linked. If your library is not compatible - update to 1.8, otherwise find some other API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is: Java virtual machines are **not** forward compatible.

A .class file that was generated by an "n+1" compiler can't be used on a "n" JVM. (unless you specifically instruct the compiler to compile for older versions of java)

Your choices:

- see if you can acquire a version of that library compiled for Java 6
- see if you can run your application on a Java 8 JRE (there is no problem running java6 classes on a *newer* JVM!)

Option 1 can get pretty ugly - as that library might have dependencies on system classes that Java6 doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to use multiples Java version or even multiples `JVMs` in the same project

If you really need this API, then you have just few choices, the best one is to upgrade all the project to use `Java 1.8`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use jars compiled under java 1.8 in an environment running at java 1.6

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can't do this. However, you may be able to find older versions of the libraries you wish to use, and those libraries may support your particular version of Java. This potentially means that you will be adopting bugs into your software, but that's just how software evolves over time.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use this 3rd party jar,
then you must compile the 3rd party jar using -target 1.6 (to target java 1.6).
Maybe you will get the source and compile it yourself or maybe you will get somebody else (the vendor, perhaps) to compile it.

All other options are:

1. Upgrade your JVM to Java 8.
2. Don't use that 3rd party jar.  Either write or find one that is compatible with java 6.